# AS3 - Using Context Menu while right mouse button is mapped to other drag event

Tags: actionscript-3, flash, contextmenu

In my AS3 program I'm trying to use a ContextMenu while also having an event tied to the right mouse button drag.  It's default behaviour that once some other event is tied to the right mouse button, that the ContextMenu gets disabled.

Is it possible to get around this to allow for both ContextMenu on a right mouse click, and my other custom event on a right mouse drag?  Or is it possible to map the context menu to another button (example map it to the middle mouse click)?

All my searching for customizing a context menu has only resulted in how to customize the menu items - so any help would be greatly appreciated! TIA.

Comment: This is a really interesting question.  At first, I thought it would be simple: disable context menu during a drag, and enable it again on drag-end.  Unfortunately, it looks like just HAVING a right-mouse-down listener suppresses the context menu!  The documentation isn't clear on this, either...Could you add a "start dragging" custom context menu element that triggers the drag'n'drop instead of always having the listener?  That's the only workaround that occurs to me off-the-cuff.

Comment: Thanks for the response @Brian, by the "start dragging" element, do you mean an item in my content menu list? I'm assuming selecting this would basically trigger something that would add an event listener for the drag, then remove it when done (thus re-enabling the context menu).  This does seem like one solution, however not one that would be great for a smooth workflow for the user!
When I first started this I thought it would be easy as well, before I realized that having anything else listening to my right mouse would automatically disable the context menu.

Comment: Yeah, something like that.  It's not a great solution, but it seems like a workaround that would allow you to keep the context menu.  I take it something like "left-mouse-down" or "ctrl-click to drag" would be problematic for other reasons?

Comment: Another thought -- you could build a custom menu-list component and show that as an overlay on right-mouse-up, if appropriate.  You'd have to live without the real context menu in that case, though.

Comment: I think the menu list component overlay might be my best option at this point! Then on my mouse up I can just check if I was dragging previous to the mouse up and not show it if I was.  I was hoping that there was some elegant solution that I was just missing somewhere! Thanks for helping brainstorm